# Query about Heisenberg uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, atomic-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, orbitals

acoording to heisenbergy uncertainty principle if the electrons  change the radius of their orbit, then it is like making transition even though the change in radius is small and they should emit radiation. But it is not happening.If the electron take the same orbit, then there may be some uncertainty in their position but we can predict the exact velocity of the electron in the orbit  by coulumb's law. That should not happen according to heisenbergy uncertainty principle. So the way to have uncertainty in both position and momentum for the electron is to change the radius of the orbit often. If it does so it is like making  transition between that two places. So we can see  huge number  of wavelengths for hydrogen atom, but there are no such wavelengths ( excluding wavelengths predicted by bohr model ) ,  is this disproves HUP?

Comment: Starting from a wrong premise ("electrons move in radial orbits") you can never prove anything either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about the quantum model of the hydrogen atom first. The electron does not in reality move around the nucleus in fixed orbits. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom) Instead, they move in orbitals and the square of the wavefunction gives the probability density of electron being at any point.